# Setting "starter" values on created() with Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to setup a default value for some state when a component is created. In practice, I want the user's preferred language `prefLang` to be based on `navigator.language` if they have not specified this through the user input.

My current approach is not working, though I did have this working before moving to use Vuex. I am getting no errors, but what is happening is that the current default value set against `prefLanf`, `UNDEF`, is being rendered instead of the output of navigate.language.

The question becomes: *how do I set an initial value for some of the state properties in the absence of user input?*

Below is an overly simplified representation of the code I'm working with:

**store.js**

```
const state ={
  userData: {
    prefLang: "UNDEF"
    // some other data..
  }
}

const getters = {
    defaultLang: () => { navigator.language.slice(0,2) }
}

const actions = {
    setDefaultLang({ state, getters }) {
        state.userData.prefLang = getters.defaultLang
    }
}
```

**Chat.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="chat-display">
        <p>{{ this.userData.prefLang }}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'chat-display',
    created() {
        this.store.dispatch('setDefaultLang')
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'defaultLang'
        ]),
        ...mapState([
            'userData'
        ])
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'setDefaultLang'
        ])
    }
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - was not returning the value of navigator.language in my getter

Answer (score 0):

### Found some problems in example:

- function defaultLagn not returning
- acess store without this.$store in component

here a example running: https://codepen.io/ptcmariano/pen/jQZmWW

```js
const mapGetters = Vuex.mapGetters;
const mapActions = Vuex.mapActions;
const mapState = Vuex.mapState;

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
          userData: {
            prefLang: "UNDEF"
            // some other data..
          }
    },
    getters: {
        defaultLang: () => { return navigator.language.slice(0,2) }
    },
    actions: {
        setDefaultLang({ state, getters }) {
            state.userData.prefLang = getters.defaultLang
        }
    }
});


new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store: store,
    template: `<div class="chat-display"> <p> lang: {{ this.userData.prefLang }}</p> </div>`,
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('setDefaultLang')
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'defaultLang'
        ]),
        ...mapState([
            'userData'
        ])
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions([
            'setDefaultLang'
        ])
    }
});
```

```html
#app
```